# Segmentation fault when doing many pushbacks to a vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I really don't know why I'm having the segmentation fault.
I'm trying to generate primes with the code below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> prime_list;

void generate_primes(int upper_limit){
    vector<bool> bool_index (upper_limit, true);
    for(int i = 2; i<upper_limit; i++){
        if (bool_index[i]){
            ::prime_list.push_back(i);
            for(int j = i*i; j<upper_limit; j+=i){
                bool_index[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    generate_primes(300000); //for big numbers it gives a segmentation fault
    for(int i: prime_list){
        cout<<i<<" ";
    }
    return 0;*/
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- [Do not include this header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).  If you are not automatically and instinctively typing in `#include <iostream>` and `#include <vector>`, then you are not learning C++ properly.

Comment: This is not a [mcve] as `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` won't compile.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `int j = i*i` -- What if `i * i` overflows an `int`?

Comment: If you run under a debugger, you'll see that the problem happens when j == -2146737495 and i == 46349

Comment: *Segmentation fault when doing many pushbacks to a vector* -- Did you debug your code to verify that the issue has anything to do with `push_back`? If you had debugged your code, you would have seen that the issue has nothing to do with the number of `push_back` calls.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, there is a overflow in `j = i * i` when `i` is `46349`. `46349 * 46349` will be too large to be represented in an `int` (given a 32 bit `int`). This is a signed integer overflow and it makes your program have *undefined behavior*. In your case, the result will most probably wrap around at `INT_MAX` and become `-2146737495`. This negative index is out of bounds of `bool_index`, which is also a cause for undefined behavior. A crash is very likely in this case.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you cause undefined behavior simply by computing `i * i` for such large `i`.  So the fix not only has to avoid using such `i*i` to index into `bool_index`; it has to avoid computing it altogether.

Comment: Ideally, the loop on `i` would only go up to `sqrt(upper_limit)`.